# How to avoid extra equation numbers while using subequations?

Tags: equations, subequations

I searched through the web but I could not find the solution to my question:

I try to write equation in the following format:

```
TYPE a:
A = {mathematics relation-a}      3.1

TYPE b: 
B = {mathematics relation-b}      3.2

TYPE c: 
C = {mathematics relation-c}      3.3
```

I tried `subequations` but the result is like this:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    TYPE_A= \\ A = \{ relqtion equation a \} \label{eq:subeq1}\\
    TYPE_B= \\ B = \{ relqtion equation b \} \label{eq:subeq2}\\
    TYPE_C= \\ C = \{ relqtion equation c \} \label{eq:subeq3}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

The result is:

```
                     TYPE a:      3.1
A = {mathematics relation-a}      3.2
                     TYPE b:      3.3 
B = {mathematics relation-b}      3.4
                     TYPE c:      3.5 
C = {mathematics relation-c}      3.6
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example so we can see what kind of code you have been using.

Comment: Could you please include your tex code into your answer, in the form of a minimal working example.

Comment: question **EDITED**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not providing any "alignment hooks" in your code; hence, everythings gets pushed against the right-hand edge. The following may be more to your liking -- note the use of the symbol `&` on all six lines, as well as the three instances of `\notag`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    &\text{TYPE A}  \notag \\ 
    &A = \{ \text{relation equation a} \} \label{eq:subeq1}\\
    &\text{TYPE B} \notag\\ 
    &B = \{ \text{relation equation b} \} \label{eq:subeq2}\\
    &\text{TYPE C} \notag\\ 
    &C = \{ \text{relation equation c} \} \label{eq:subeq3}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `\notag` for the lines with the labels and `alignat`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
&\makebox[0pt][l]{Type A:}\notag \\
&& A &= 1+1 \label{eq:subeq1}\\
\makebox[0pt][l]{Type B:}\notag \\
&& B &= 2+2 \label{eq:subeq2}\\
&\makebox[0pt][l]{Type C:}\notag \\
&& C &= 3+3 \label{eq:subeq3}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]